# VSCode Test Discovery Conflict, lib vs local

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I am experiencing an issue with Visual Studio Code test discovery hoping to get some insight. I believe this is due to a conflict between the Python `lib` vs. **local**.

**Context**

I have a custom package (let's call it `alphalib`) that follow a similar file structure below.

The `MainFolder` is add to the VSCode workspace. There are multiple tests within `alphalib` as well as other folders such as `FirstLevelCharlie`. Due to certain previously unknown reason, `alphalib` is also configured as a custom package with a custom Python setup, and is repackaged and put in the `<python>/lib/python3.9` folder (for easy distribution I am assuming, don't have too much details...). It is packaged with `SubpackageA`, `SubpackageB`, and `SubpackageC` (which on the local folder is on a different level)

So now I have a Python environment with with `alphalib` in the `<python>/lib/python3.9` folder, and `alphalib` in the local path (`MainFolder/FirstLevelBravo/alphalib`). This seem to be confusing VSCode on where to look for the `import` for `alphalib` and is throwing error stating it's unable to find `alphalib.SubpackageC`. Which I believe VSCode is trying to look at the local folder instead of the Python environment.

But within VSCode editor itself, it is able to discover all the Subpackage fine and code completion detected `alphalib.SubpackageC`.

Does anyone have any suggestion on a workaround for this? I am unable to change the structure of `MainFolder` because it is a big repository with many people working on it, but other stuff I can change.

```
MainFolder
- FirstLevelAlpha
- FirstLevelBravo
    - SecondLevelA
    - alphalib
        - SubpackageA
        - SubpackageB
    - SecondLevelC
    - SubpackageC
    - ...
- FirstLevelCharlie
- FirstLevelDelta
- ...
```